# Find all matching keys and values in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Pandas DF like the one below were the key is "state county" I want to find all the zip codes that are associated with each key.

On a small scale I accomplished this using a loop but it is not efficient for the 50,000 keys I need to check. Is there a programing concept I can use to solve this without having to check each line against all the other lines?

**Original df**

| state county | zip |
| --- | --- |
| VA Culpeper County | 20106 |
| VA Fauquier County | 20115 |
| VA Loudoun County | 20101 |
| VA Loudoun County | 20102 |
| VA Loudoun County | 20103 |
| VA Loudoun County | 20104 |
| VA Loudoun County | 20105 |
| VA Loudoun County | 20107 |
| VA Manassas City | 20108 |
| VA Manassas city | 20110 |
| VA Manassas City | 20113 |
| VA Prince William County | 20109 |
| VA Prince William County | 20111 |
| VA Prince William County | 20112 |

**Output df**

| state county | zip 1 | zip 2 | zip 3 | zip 4 | zip 5 | zip 6 | zip 7 | zip 8 | zip 9 | zip 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VA Culpeper County | 20106 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| VA Fauquier County | 20115 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| VA Loudoun County | 20101 | 20102 | 20103 | 20104 | 20105 | 20107 |  |  |  |  |
| VA Manassas City | 20108 | 20110 | 20113 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| VA Prince William County | 20109 | 20111 | 20112 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Are you using pandas or what structure is a DF? If so you should specify it is a pandas dataframe and tag the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collect all the zips for every state and then create a new DataFrame

```py
df2 = df.groupby('state county').agg({'zip': list})
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2.zip.tolist(), index=df2.index)
```

You can rename the columns of the resulting DataFrame, so that they are in the form `zip <n>`:

```py
df3.columns = list(map("zip {}".format, df3.columns + 1))
```

```sh
df3
                          zip 1  zip 2  zip 3  zip 4  zip 5  zip 6
state county                                                      
VA Culpeper County        20106   None   None   None   None   None
VA Fauquier County        20115   None   None   None   None   None
VA Loudoun County         20101  20102  20103  20104  20105  20107
VA Manassas City          20108  20110  20113   None   None   None
VA Prince William County  20109  20111  20112   None   None   None
```